# Divisibility in the homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the $k$-sphere (I'm particularly interested in $k=3$). For each positive integer $n$ let $P_{n}$ be the set of primes that divide the order of $\pi_{i}S^{k}$ for some $i\leq n$.

Does the cardinality of $P_{n}$ tend to infinity with $n$?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. In fact $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} P_n $ is the set of all primes.  Serre  proved that, for each odd prime $p$, there is some very predictable $p$-torsion in $\pi_{k+(p-1)}(S^k)$, for example.

There is a very nice theorem of McGibbon and Neisendorfer (proving, I think, a conjecture of Serre) that implies and vastly generalizes this.

> **Theorem (McGibbon & Neisendorfer).**  Let $X$ be a simply-connected finite complex such that $\widetilde{H}_*(X; \mathbb{Z}/p) \neq 0$.
>   Then $\pi_n X$ contains $p$-torsion for infinitely many values of $n$.

Comment: Taking $Q_n$ be the set of primes that divide the order of $\pi_nS^3$, do we also know whether the cardinality of $Q_n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I guess it is assumed that $k\ge 2$. Is there any other implicit assumption on $k$?

Comment: For sure $k\neq 1$, but all other $k$ are ok.